# Missing resource exception when trying to hit an application deployed on WebSphere Application Server

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, websphere

I am getting an error as pasted below when I try to display a jsp(/jsp/login.jsp) page which is present in the application which I have deployed on WebSphere Application Server successfully.

```
[15/01/14 11:31:16:451 GMT] 0000002d servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /jsp/login.jsp in application CAA application. Exception created : java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle com.fp.config.MessageResources, key en 

  at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:365)
  at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:125)
  at com.fp.websec.util.validation.UserMessages.getMessage(UserMessages.java:168)
  at com.fp.websec.util.validation.UserMessages.getMessage(UserMessages.java:94)
  at com.fp.websec.util.validation.Util.getTargetURL(Util.java:651)
  at com.ibm._jsp._login._jspService(_login.java:162)
  at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1663)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
  at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
  at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:241)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:445)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:504)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:301)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:275)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)

 [15/01/14 11:31:16:467 GMT] 0000002d LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
 [15/01/14 11:31:16:483 GMT] 0000002d webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[/jsp/login.jsp]: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle com.fp.config.MessageResources, key en

  at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:365)
  at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:125)
  at com.fp.websec.util.validation.UserMessages.getMessage(UserMessages.java:168)
  at com.fp.websec.util.validation.UserMessages.getMessage(UserMessages.java:94)
  at com.fp.websec.util.validation.Util.getTargetURL(Util.java:651)
  at com.ibm._jsp._login._jspService(_login.java:162)
  at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1663)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
  at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
  at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:241)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:445)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:504)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:301)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:275)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)

[15/01/14 11:31:16:498 GMT] 0000002d servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /jsp/internalServerError.jsp in application CAA application. Exception created : java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle com.fp.config.externalResources, key en_GB

  at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:365)
  at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:104)
  at com.fp.websec.util.validation.Util.getExternalResource(Util.java:112)
  at com.ibm._jsp._internalServerError._jspService(_internalServerError.java:136)
  at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1663)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
  at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
  at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:241)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:341)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3262)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3859)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:445)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:504)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:301)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:275)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)

[15/01/14 11:31:16:514 GMT] 0000002d LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[15/01/14 11:31:16:514 GMT] 0000002d webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception  The server cannot use the error page specified for your application because of the exception printed below.
[15/01/14 11:31:16:529 GMT] 0000002d webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception:
```

I am new to WAS and I don't know whats wrong with the deployment the file which it is searching is present in a jar file which is there in the files generated by the `build.xml`

I know this might be some silly mistake but your help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely failing to locate message resource files it requires. Both `com.fp.config.MessageResources` and `com.fp.config.externalResources` are are looking for properties files that contain internationalized message text.

Can you locate any such files that are in the source code but not included in jars/wars?

Comment: Hi dbreaux,

Thanks for your reply on this. I do have a MessageResources_en.properties and can locate this in the source code but this file is not included in any of the jar files. Might be the definite reason for getting this error.

Comment: Hi there is a properties file but I am not sure how to add that to my .ear file. When I build the application it generates a xyz.ear file which needs to be deployed on WAS 7. But this ear doesnt contain the requires properties file, please help.

Comment: Depends on where that `com.fp` code is expecting it. Often that's in the classpath, which could be within a Jar or in a WAR file's `WEB-INF/classes`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `messages_en.properties` is missing in your build path. check whether the properties file is in the proper location.

Comment: I dont have any file called messages_en.properties I do have a file called CAAConstants.java which is packed in a jar file and placed in \config folder. Still it cant find this file.